# How to automate 'Toast Message' using robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, toast, toastr

In my web application (Python/Django) there are two different toast messages for error and success of the action.
Text contents on both toasts are different for different action results and location of displaying is also multiple (Left corner/Right corner/Header/Footer, etc).
It displays for 3 seconds and then disappeared in fading mode.

How to automate it using robot framework as there is no fixed locators?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question, add code that you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Nothing I have tried yet as no locators found...checking for some options.

Comment: There must be a locator that is the toast element in the DOM, assuming that the toast is part of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wait until element is visible](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Is%20Visible), giving it a locator unique to the message.

For example, let's assume the toast is implemented as a div that looks like this:

```
<div class='toast'>Record submitted</div>
```

You could use the keyword like this:

```
Wait until element is visible  
...  //div[contains(@class, 'toast') and text()='Record submitted']
```

You could also just wait for the toast element to appear, get the text, and then assert on the text.

```
Wait until element is visible  //div[contains(@class, 'toast')]
${message}=  Get text  //div[contains(@class, 'toast')]
Should be equal  ${message}  Record submitted
```